# IKEA kitchen drawer - push to open

Tags: drawers

I am trying to find a way of getting my kitchen to be fully handleless, but the more i research and try different thing the more it gets tricky. How can i make a push to open drawers on Ikea maximera kitchen units?

Example drawer:

[image]

I know that Blum used to make kitchen hardware for IKEA but i don't think this is the case any longer. Also i am running Gloss white, so i can't use VOXTORP fronts as they are NOT in gloss white...

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Great idea, but it may be hard to retrofit.  Normal drawers are designed to sit flush, and better quality hardware encourages the drawer to close when almost closed.  Any form for push release requires some travel beyond the closed position (that isn't triggered by normal closure).  There are lots of cabinet door catches that are push release, but they leave the door open just a crack.  If you want it to open a loaded drawer a useful amount, you would need a big spring mechanism or something like a window weight pulley system to open the drawer.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you design a retrofit system, the world will beat a path to your door.  Maybe base it on the mechanism in automatic umbrellas.

Answer (score 2):

The IKEA Maximera drawers are a special order version of Blum's Tandembox antaro line. Blum's name is stamped on the drawer slides.  They appear to be almost identical.

There are a couple videos on YouTube, where people show that they have removed the soft closer on other types of IKEA drawers (not SEKTION) , and used the IKEA push to open unit mounted to the sidewall instead.

Looking through the Blum catalog, they offer a push-to-open accessory branded "Tip-On" which they sell a version for Tandembox drawers.  It appears to mount under the drawer near the front of the slide.  It may just attach to the the Maximera, hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this. It requires some engineering but it works great.

I have built jigs and made retrofit brackets that allow you to use blum’s tip-on mechanism with ikea’s maximera kitchen drawers.

I also installed this on 13 drawers of my own kitchen and it works very well.

Here’s a video of the system in action. It’s soft close and push to open and triggers evenly on both sides of the drawer, irrespective of which side you push on.

If you’d like more info then drop me a line on pushopendrawer@gmail.com

https://youtu.be/ACmLeBkIBaA